# Regular expression (rexep) with grouping for sublime text 2 build system

Tags: regex, less, sublimetext

I am trying to implement error capturing with Sublime Text 2 build system for a LESS pre-processor on Windows. I need a single regular expression with grouping for filename with path and error line number.

Pre-processor output is following:

```
ERR: 
  type: Parse
  message: Syntax Error on line 6
  index: 131
  filename: D:\workflow\less-css\test\test.less
  line: 6
  extract:   asd,},
[Finished]
```

Here is regular expression guidelines for *file_regex* option:

> The file_regex option uses a Perl-style regular expression to capture up to four fields of error information from the build program’s output, namely: file name, line number, column number and error message. Use groups in the pattern to capture this information. The file name field and the line number field are required.

I am only recently started to learn regular expressions so any help is very appreciated. Again, regexp should return 2 group items - filename with path and line number. Both are present in pre-processor output.

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the captures don't have to be in the order you desccribe? This will capture the message, filename and line number into buffers 1, 2 and 3.

```
/message:\s+(.+?)\s*\n.*filename:\s+(.+?)\s*\n.*line:\s+(.+?)\s*\n/s
```

Given your example error above, the captures would be

```
1: Syntax Error on line 6
2: D:\workflow\less-css\test\test.less
3: 6
```

Alternatively, using lookahead assertions, the following PHP code stores things in the right order

```
<?php
$err = '
ERR:
  type: Parse
  message: Syntax Error on line 6
  index: 131
  filename: D:\workflow\less-css\test\test.less
  line: 6
  extract:   asd,},
';
$re = '/(?=.*filename:\s+(.+?)\s*\n)(?=.*line:\s+(.+?)\s*\n)()(?=.*message:\s+(.+?)\s*\n)/s';
preg_match($re, $err, $match);
print_r($match);
?>
```

Note that I have inserted an empty capture as a placeholder for the column number. If the value with the 'index' label is the column number then just duplicate the other field captures and alter the text.

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => D:\workflow\less-css\test\test.less
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 
    [4] => Syntax Error on line 6
)
```

Comment: It occurs to me that `index` may be the column number. Hopefully you can expand the regex to include this field if it is required? The pattern for each field is the same except for the label text.

Comment: Unfortunately, order is important. I guess I have to drop error message for now. Filepath and line number will suffice. Also, can you advise how I can escape this expression correctly? It's assigned to config variable so python raw output is not possible.

Comment: If your implementation of regular expressions allows for lookahead assertions, then this `/(?=.*filename:\s+(.+?)\s*\n)(?=.*line:\s+(.+?)\s*\n)(?=.*message:\s+(.+?)\s*\n)/s` will return the fields in the right order. Just doubling all backslashes should suffice to escape the expression.

Comment: Better still, just put the expression as it is in single quotes. No escaping is necessary.

Comment: I have edited my original answer to show how this would work in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answers. Unfortunately, your regex is not working to me. You can try it online with Python regexp tester http://re-try.appspot.com/. Currently, I am using this modified rexep of yours `.*filename:\s+(.+?)\s*\n.*line:\s+(.+?)\s*\n` and it works ok.

Comment: It works fine on that site. You need to need to remove the bounding slashes, choose the *search* method and enable the *DOTALL* option (which is the equivalent of the /s qualifier on my regex).